# Проблема имплементации SOLID при наследовании метода со switch-блоком

Tags: ооп, классы, шаблоны-проектирования, solid

Недавно в процессе работы столкнулся с интересной проблемой имплементации принципов [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29) на практике, которой хочу поделиться с сообществом.

Допустим, есть у нас функция, открытый член класса (в данном случае название класса и функции неважно), которой на вход передается единственный параметр (допустим целочисленный). В теле функции происходит проверка входного параметра с помощью блока `switch`. Внутри блока `switch` имеется несколько веток `case` (сейчас 5), где в случае совпадения происходят некоторые действия влияющие на возвращаемый результат. Казалось бы проще простого, но...

Главная проблема - это каким образом я могу обеспечить возможность расширяемости функционала данного класса в случае, если в будущем возникнет необходимость обрабатывать большее количество веток `case` (то есть, еще несколько, помимо уже имеющихся 5-ти) без модификации тела уже имеющейся функции (SOLID, open/closed principle)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не вдаваясь в то, что там действительно могут быть проблемы с архитектурой

```
class A
  public meth(int i)
    switch i
      case 1
        ...

class B extends A
  public meth(int i)
    switch i
      case 7
        ...
      default
        return A.meth(i)
```

Comment: А как вызывающий код должен решать, какой класс инстанциировать и вызывать?

Comment: @andreycha если с точки зрения внутренней работы языка - согласно типу, который используется, если с точки зрения программиста - уже у самого класса должно быть достаточно ясное название, чтобы понять, зачем его использовать. Без конкретного примера не сказать, если это, скажем, *корректор значений*, то расбуетсяширенный класс (в случае, если у него ведется пре-обработка данных) может реализовывать какой-то единичный специфический случай, где исходный корректор не отрабатывает правильно.

Answer (score 11):

Не существует "абстрактного подхода" к применению принципов проектирования и уж тем более, нет такого понятия как "имплементация принципов на практике".

Принципы проектирования были сформулированы для решения определенных проблем, в заданном наборе контрекстов.

Вот, например, [SRP](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/08/single-responsibility-principle.html) возник в результате неспособности человеческого мозга справиться с наплывом сложности. [OCP](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/08/open-closed-principle.html) возник как необходимость параллельной разработки программных систем множеством людей. [LSP](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ca/2014/09/liskov-substitution-principle.html) возник для решения проблемы нанследования и формализации того, когда наследование корректно моделирует отношение "Является", а когда - нет.

Не зная контекста задачи нельзя дать очень точного ответа, но исходя из описания я могу сделать следующий вывод: если сложность метода, который оперирует переданным аргументом относительно невысока (пол-экрана кода), код простой и понятный, то с ним все в порядке и никаких изменений вносить в него категорически не следует.

Полиморфизмы и фабрики сделают дизайн сложным в понимании и сопровождении. Простой switch - это наиболее естественный способ решения проблемы, когда вся логика находится в одном месте.

Не нужно пытаться предугадать изменения требований. Это все равно не получится сделать. Если внесение изменений будет продиктовано изменениями требований (и появится еще один case в блоке switch), то код менять все равно придется. Придется еще и тесты поправить, да и задеплоить изменения куда следует.

OCP не подразумевает гибкость решения. Он говорит об изоляции изменения нужными местами.

Бертран Мейер, автор OCP отдельно выделяет дополнительное правило, которое он называет "Принципом единственного выбора", который заключается в том, что система не нарушает OCP, если некоторое решение принимается в одном месте.

**Вывод: не нужно ничего менять. С методом все в порядке, пока подобных switch-ей больше нет в приложении. Никакие принципы не нарушаются, котята целы, а клиенты довольны. И не гонитесь за принципами, ради принципов!**

З.Ы. Довольно подробно я рассматривал принцип LSP и принцип единственного выбора в статье [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2014/08/open-closed-principle.html).

UPDATE: как раз нендавно был поднят вопрос о YAGNI и SOLID принципах в вопросе ["Нарушает ли OCP и DIP (из SOLID) принцип YAGNI?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556137/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-ocp-%D0%B8-dip-%D0%B8%D0%B7-solid-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-yagni/556526#556526).

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно заменить конструкцию `switch` на полиморфизм: наследование или стратегию. Я бы выбрал второй вариант ("Предпочитайте композицию наследованию").

Например, был у вас метод:

```
void Foo(int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine("Zero");
            break;
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("One");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Two");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown");
            break;
    }
}
```

Введем интерфейс стратегии:

```
interface INumberStrategy
{
    void Do();
}
```

И его наследники, по одному на каждую ветку `switch`:

```
class ZeroNumberStrategy : INumberStrategy
{
    void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Zero");
    }
}

class OneNumberStrategy : INumberStrategy
{
    void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("One");
    }
}

class TwoNumberStrategy : INumberStrategy
{
    void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Two");
    }
}

class UnknownNumberStrategy : INumberStrategy
{
    void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown");
    }
}
```

Теперь наш метод превращается в:

```
void Foo(INumberStrategy strategy)
{
    numberStrategy.Do();
}
```

Плюс вам понадобится место, где будут создаваться нужные стратегии:

```
class NumberStrategyFactory
{
    INumberStrategy CreateStrategy(int i)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0:
                return new ZeroNumberStrategy();
            case 1:
                return new OneNumberStrategy();
            case 2:
                return new TwoNumberStrategy();
            default:
                return UnknownNumberStrategy();
        }
    }
}
```

Т.о. при добавлении новой ветки алгоритма мы не будем менять исходный класс. Мы добавим новый класс стратегии, соответствующий новой ветке, и изменим фабрику (от добавления новой ветки в фабрике уже никуда не деться :)).

Конечно, на таком простом примере это все выглядит излишним, но в сложной системе (я так полагаю, вы свой пример упростили) такие изменения оправдывают себя. Также важно помнить о том, что SOLID ради SOLID'а, шаблоны ради шаблонов и т.п. -- это неверный путь. Код писать нужно как можно проще, главное не в ущерб расширяемости и поддерживаемости. И во многих случаях может быть действительно проще остаться с изначальным `switch'ем`.

Comment: А что, если вместо фабрики использовать инкапсулированный Map<значение, IStragegy>, а потом каким-то методом ему давать новые реализации в начале работы приложения? Вроде бы это избавит от необходимости фабрику переписывать, но сомнения все равно есть.

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно и так. Фабрика просто более классический способ. В любом случае, мапу также придется обновлять при добавлении новой "ветки".

Answer (score 1):

Вариация решения от Etki, которая гарантирует выполнение метода основного класса (но и запрещает изменять реализацию для описанных в нем значений)

```
class A {
    protected methDelegate(int i) {}
    public final meth(int i) {
        switch i {
        case 1
            ...
        default
            methDelegate(i);
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    protected methDelegate(int i) {
        switch i {
        case 7
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Тут пока что остается проблема с блоком default из класса А. Если что-то должно выполняться, когда ни один вариант не подошел — как заставить B вызывать этот блок?

- Сделать метод `defaultDelegate()` и надеяться, что `methDelegate()` его вызовет?
- Костыль, в котором `methDelegate` возвращает `false` в `default` и `true` иначе?

Comment: Open-Closed Principle = открыто для расширения, закрыто для модификации. Да и не должен класс ни в чем полагаться на наследников, если только он не абстрактный.

Comment: @Etki: так и в вашем варианте А не может полагаться, что В вызовет его метод. Может вообще все варианты перебрать самостоятельно.

Comment: В моем он действительно не знает о наследниках и о том, как его будут использовать. Здесь он пропихивает часть реализации детям.

Comment: @Etki c т.з. того, что класс А открыт для расширения и закрыт для модификации это решение абсолютно симметрично вашему. И класс А не полагается на детей: у него будет своя дефолтная реализация `methDelegate`, а кто там и как его расширяет -- не его дело (главное чтобы в пределах LSP).

Comment: @andreycha он-таки закрыт, потому что с meth ничего сделать нельзя. Я не могу внедрить никакую обработку перед ним. Если у меня будет сужение функционала, и некоторые валидные для А значения будут невалидны для Б, с этим ничего нельзя будет сделать.

Comment: @Etki да, вы правы. Плюс есть проблема с тем, какой класс инстанциировать и вызывать. Впрочем, к вашему решению тот же вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://refactoring.guru/ru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) описана ваша проблема и её решение. Коротко: `switch-case` заменить полиморфизмом.

Comment: Не прокатит, если каждому классу нужно обрабатывать набор значений. По ссылке идет привязка одного значения `type` к одному классу.

Comment: @Vesper идея как раз в том, чтобы заменить набор значений на набор классов. нет значений - нет проблемы.

Comment: @PashaPash Это-то я понял, но я понял ОПа так, что в метод передается расширяемый набор значений, а ограничения на объект не описаны, поэтому предположил синглтон (ибо решение в случае без ограничений должно работать без дополнительных ограничений). А у синглтона не бывает полиморфизма.

Comment: @Vesper Предположение, что там синглтон - это и есть дополнительное ограничение (== нельзя использовать полиморфизм). Очень странно предполагать запрет на использование полиморфизма (и заодно и наследования) в вопросе на котором стоит тег ООП.

Answer (score 0):

SOLID - это принципы проектирования. Их нельзя "имплементировать". Их можно только применять (или не применять).

> Каким образом я могу обеспечить возможность расширяемости функционала данного класса в случае, если в будущем возникнет необходимость обрабатывать большее количество веток case (то есть, еще несколько, помимо уже имеющихся 5-ти) без модификации тела уже имеющейся функции (SOLID, open/closed principle)?

Ваша формулировка подразумевает следующие ограничения:

- код надо написать раз и навсегда
- в этом коде есть switch
- на вход кода подается целое число
- в зависимости от его значения нужно вызвать соответствующий код.

Последние два ограничения подразумевают switch. Или его аналоги с регистрацией обработчиков для каждого значения (вроде `Dictionary<int, Fun>`). Или еще какой-то финт, который на самом деле сводится к хорошо спрятанному switch.

Единственный вариант с таким набором ограничений - это написать новый метод, который обработает новые ветки. А для старых вызовет старый метод (как в примере @Etki). Иначе вы нарушите Open/Closed. А это плохо (по крайней мере все так считают).

---

На самом же деле у вас *уже* нарушены и Open/Closed и Single Responsibility Principle. Т.к. у вас есть явно больше чем одна причина для изменения кода:

- может поменяться логика для 1
- может поменяться логика для 2
- могут быть добавлены новые значения

Open/Closed был нарушен в тот момент, когда вы написали switch. Как не нарушить уже нарушенный принцип? Никак. Надо сначала починить то, что есть.

Вам нужно убирать switch - это как-то убрать целое число из параметров. Например, заменив его на набор классов с общим интерфейсом (как в решении от @andreycha)

---

Для применения принципов проектирования (любых) надо осознавать какую проблему каждый из этих принципов решает. Open/Closed решает проблему "как не поломать старый код".

Так вот, кроме фанатичного применения блестящей идеи 30-летней давности "а давайте старый код не менять!" есть куча современных альтернатив.

Например, вместо того, чтобы думать как применить <sub>s</sub>O<sub>lid</sub> к коду со свитчем на 5 вариантов можно **написать на него тесты**! Еще лучше - написать тесты до того, как этот switch будет написан! И вообще писать тесты вне зависимости от того, умеете вы применять SOLID или нет.

А Open/Closed применять не как бездумный "запрет на редактирование", а как принцип, предлагающий "дописывать/расширять" код вместо "переписывания".