# Типизация - языки со "множественной типизацией" (union types) аргументов методов?

Tags: php, ооп, любой-язык, теория-типов

В качестве языка примера буду использовать PHP , для простоты.  Поясню сразу суть вопроса. В современных языках, особенно это касается интерпритируемых, есть типизация традиционно не строгая:

```
function join($a){
   return is_array($a) ? implode('', $a) : $a;
}
```

А есть типизация строгая:

```
function join(array $a) : string{
  return implode('', $a);
}
```

Есть ещё, например в C++ шаблонная типизация:

```
template <class T, class R>
R* join(T * array, int count)
{
    R *output = new R(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      output += array[i] ;
    return output;
}
```

Есть ещё в C++ перегрузка по типам, но она весьма не гибка и громоздка, как и шаблонная типизация, последняя вдобавок ещё и не читаема.

Но очень не хватает типизации множественной (*как я узнал - это называется [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)*) - хотелось бы следующее:

```
function join(array|Iterator|ICollectable $input) : string|null{
    /*какой-то код обработки*/
}
```

**Вопрос** - есть ли языки, поддерживающие подобный синтаксис ограничения по типам, если да, то какие? Если нет, то каковы причины, чем концепция плоха?

Почему возникает вопрос отсутствия встроенной поддержки сего - программисты языков с variance-типами, обычно пишут в коментах метода что-то вроде:

```
/**
   * Some function describe
   * 
   * @param array|ISomeList $list ...
   * @return false|string ...
   */
```

Но в объявлении ф-ии они вынуждены не делать явной отсылки к типу(полагаясь на комментарии), оставляя variance типы:

```
public function someFunction($list) {... return $some;};
```

Это встречается регулярно в более чем серьёзных фреймворках, которые не могут принебречь читаемостью кода ради строгой типизации.

В итоге при исследовании кода без явного указания желаемых типов: понижается читаемость. Комменты не дают 100% гарантии ограничения типов: программист, как и IDE не может точно знать - что может придти во входном параметре. А при работе программы - если вдруг во входной параметр попало не то что нужно: не происходит ошибок/предупреждений , что усложняет ловлю ошибок, понижает стабильность.

Наоборот же при использовании только строгих типов - безальтернативно усложняется вся система в целом: количество классов растёт геометрично. Что ещё хуже, ведь НЕ-строгость типов работает на простые архитектурные решения и читаемый код, и в случае скриптовых языков ей нельзя принебрегать.

**UPD**:
Да, конечно такая фича не совсем ложится на принципы ООП. Но это было бы поводом эти принципы пересматривать - т.к. они [очень обходчиво не учитывают](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/10/about-design-principles.html) "геометрический рост количества классов" . А также union-типизация работает совместно с [утиной типизацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) - что я бы минусом не назвал, но это большое поле для споров.

**UPD2**:
Если возникает вопрос обоснованности мульти-типов: Более живой пример из PHP - представлено объявление важной, часто используемой функции выборщика объектов из БД-таблиц (db-table-маппера) Zend фреймворка (1.9) класс Zend_Db_Table_Abstract .

```
/**
 * Fetches all rows.
 *
 * Honors the Zend_Db_Adapter fetch mode.
 *
 * @param string|array|Zend_Db_Table_Select $where  OPTIONAL An SQL WHERE clause or Zend_Db_Table_Select object.
 * @param string|array                      $order  OPTIONAL An SQL ORDER clause.
 * @param int                               $count  OPTIONAL An SQL LIMIT count.
 * @param int                               $offset OPTIONAL An SQL LIMIT offset.
 * @return Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract The row results per the Zend_Db_Adapter fetch mode.
 */
public function fetchAll($where = null, $order = null, $count = null, $offset = null)
{
    if (!($where instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Select)) {
        $select = $this->select();

        if ($where !== null) {
            $this->_where($select, $where);
        }

        if ($order !== null) {
            $this->_order($select, $order);
        }

        if ($count !== null || $offset !== null) {
            $select->limit($count, $offset);
        }

    } else {
        $select = $where;
    }

    $rows = $this->_fetch($select);

    $data  = array(
        'table'    => $this,
        'data'     => $rows,
        'readOnly' => $select->isReadOnly(),
        'rowClass' => $this->getRowClass(),
        'stored'   => true
    );

    $rowsetClass = $this->getRowsetClass();
    if (!class_exists($rowsetClass)) {
        Zend_Loader::loadClass($rowsetClass);
    }
    return new $rowsetClass($data);
}
```

Первый аргумент по замыслу разработчика может иметь один из нескольких типов. Это нужно, чтобы потенциальному пользователю метода(программисту) было очень просто уместить в голове маппер. Ведь он может вызвать из кода этот метод по-разному, но метод при этом остаётся тот-же:

```
$table->fetchAll('user_id in (1,2,5)');
$table->fetchAll(['user_id < 100', 'gender = "male"']);
$table->fetchAll( $table->select()->where('user_id IN (?)', $userIdsArray) );
```

Один метод легко запомнить, это хорошо ложится в голову. В то время, как программисту метода fetchAll не хочется размазывать логику одной задачи (выбора объектов из базы данных) на несколько перегруженных методов внутри себя - он хочет чтобы всё было в одном месте, чтобы открывший код понял сразу что и в каком порядке работает. Как минимум это соответствует [SRP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) - обязанность у метода одна: выбрать из БД объекты.

То есть предоставляется целый язык для общения с БД-таблицей. Это больше сервис для программиста, нежели просто метод. И такие методы во фреймворках: каждый второй, потому что фреймворк должен быть прежде всего удобным программисту. Программист не должен вникать в "тысячи классов" - чтобы пользоватся фичей - вот это яркий пример решения вопроса читаемости кода, в котором пригодились бы union types.

**UPD3**:
Оказывается разработчики PHP, как подсказали в коментах, [тоже думали ввести эту концепцию](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types) в 2015 году, но на голосовании - отклонили.

Comment: TypeScript например

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian круто, теперь я уважаю TypeScript . Без этой фичи это излишнее "заковывание в цепи" JS

Comment: Кстати ActionScript(и возможно в будущем до этого дойдет EcmaScript) больше склоняются к типизации duck + strict на выбор. В этом случае он мне нравится больше, чем union и имеет смысл. То есть половина реализации TypeScript, если можно так выразиться.

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/union_types

Comment: @Алексей Уколов , понятно, то есть всё уже написано для PHP , но отклонено год назад. Очень жаль, надеюсь вопрос ещё раз поднимут и примут)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, я помню, что где-то читал, что это предложение рассматривают снова, но никак не могу найти ссылку и в списке RFC его нет...

Comment: @Алексей Уколов , да - у них там проблемы какие-то со сведением типов, как я прочитал. То есть требуешь ты в методе int | float а в метод пришёл string - к чему приводить? Но поскольку php уже язык union-типов в коментах - это меньшее из зол..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересный вопрос. Не знаю как в других языках обстоят дела, но в `scala` то что вы хотите сделать, решается так:

Использованием `pattern matching`

```
def f1(obj: Any) = obj match {
  case x: Array[String] => println("is array")
  case x: String => println("is string")
  case _ => println("")
}
```

Так же, есть возможность определить какие методы должны быть у типа аргумента. Например.

```
case class A() {
 def m1() = "m1 is invoked"
 def m2() = println("m2 is invoked") } 

def f2(obj: {def m1(): String}) = {
    println(obj.m1())
}

val obj = A()
f2(obj)
```

Comment: Прикольная реализация, то есть obj match это некий лаконичный аггрегатор адаптеров, встроенный на уровне языка, адаптирующий прямо в объявлении ф-ии. В разных языках разные фишки - эта тоже весьма интересна, я не против, еслиб такое в PHP встроили)

Comment: @Artem Konovalov поясните подробнее свой код, ни одну строчку не могу расшифровать.

Comment: @stas0k pattern matching это такой паттерн, широко используемый в фун.языках. В f1 мы передаем объект obj, любого типа и  в блоках case сопоставляем их с типами, а далее идет обработка, этакий switch на стероидах. Во втором случая, мы вовсе не определяем тип, а говорим, что должен быть реализован метод m1 у типа параметра.

Answer (score 3):

Любая конструкция должна иметь обоснование: зачем это нужно, какие плюсы оно дает, какие минусы оно дает.

Из теории проектирования мы знаем, что программная единица должна выполнять строго отведенную под нее задачу-алгоритм. Наличие подобной семантики подразумевает, что код будет как называется "и жнец, и чтец, и на дуде игрец". Это полностью рушит логику и порождает плохой стиль программирования. К тому же появляется очень много вопросов по поводу его использования.

К примеру, что ожидать от него в ответ? И как потом с полученным предлагаете работать?

```
int|bool|string someValueResult = goodNews(); ???
```

Это получается, что бы удостовериться в полученном результате, я должен сделать еще двадцать проверок действительно ли мне вернули строку или может быть массив? Или как предлагается работать внутри кода? Опять же, я не думаю, что есть алгоритмы которые умеют хорошо и гармонично работать с разнообразными типами. Все равно придется вернуться к комментариям и прочитать, что делает код и как.

Если уж так хочется, проще сделать собственные классы или методы, который будет разруливать типы внутри и выдавать TypeError, чем гадать, что же на самом деле попало к нам в метод и как с этим работать. И проще всегда работать с чем-то унифицированным.

Плюсов в общем-то почти не вижу, без этого можно спокойно обойтись.

Comment: Плюсы - это прежде всего повышение читаемости кода. Как прогер, который давно слез с С++ на языки, где желаемый тип тогда явно вообще нельзя было указать: отсутствие типа более чем имеет право на жизнь. И в безтипных языках - проектирование гораздо более читаемо, расширяемо: оно более перспективное. Также (только что узнал термин) union типы - затыкают дыру в отладке https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html . У программистов бестипных языков также принято думать при разработке, что на входе может быть что угодно . См. конец вопроса.

Comment: То есть хотел бы пояснить - я считаю, что главные приоритеты в программировании это не следование принципам ООП . А читаемость кода, наряду с его стабильностью и отлавливаемостью ошибок в нём. Нет ничего лучше кода - который читается как книга. А вот SOLID - давно переименовать из "принципы" в "способы разрешения проблем" , эти проблемы в variance-языках решаются иногда гораздо проще, без усложнения понимания/объёма кода. Как и многие паттерны ООП упраздняются вовсе (не требуются) при наличии variance . Единственная проблема - отлаживаемость, решаемая union типами.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр читаемость кода тут спорный вопрос, того же самого и даже большего можно добиться, если использовать автодокументирование и IDE которое высветит описание при наведении мыши. В остальном я не вижу никакого преимущества в отладке, даже по приведенной документации видно, что все равно начинают плодиться вместо классов бесконечные `if...elseif...else` конструкции. Чем принципиально отличается передача бестипового значения по сравнению с union-типами? На самом деле хотелось бы увидеть реальный пример, который бы доказывал удобство именно union по сравнению с variance + strict.

Comment: есть утиная типизация вместо `if...elseif...else` есть операторы, которые по-разному работают между разных типов. Есть много рабочих примеров из именитого Zend фреймворка и других для PHP, но это не влезет в рамки коммента. Есть рабочие задачи вроде - когда метод класса должен работать только с определёнными наследниками абстрактного класса, утиным полиморфизмом - приходится делать в начале метода `if (! ($some instanceof B || $some instanceof D) ) {throw ..; /*или*/ return null;}`. А с документацией - меняется код, надо менять документацию, что на практике не делается у средняков.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр хорошо, но почему в таком случае Вы не хотите в языке с утиной типизацией завести две типизированные функции, которые будут работать каждая со своим видом объекта? В этом случае Вы получаете отличное разделение кода на отдельные части с хорошей мастабируемостью(убрать, добавить не перелопачивая весь код): `function myFunc(someVar: B) :Int { ...  } function myFunc(someVar: A) :String { ... }`? Почему именно union считаете более подходящим решением, а не ошибкой проектирования в которую свалено все подряд.

Comment: потому что код этих функций фактически может дублироваться. Дублирование кода - первый враг кода. Мы конечно можем вынести это в промежуточный абстрактный класс, но это во первых усложнит читаемость, во вторых обрежет нам совместное существование методов `function isModerated(Company|Group $item)` `function isConfirmed(Event|Group $item)` в одном классе. А иногда спасает ручное сведение типов `function getSign(User|array $user){ $user = is_array($user) ? new User($user) : $user; /*куча остального кода*/}` . Теория ООП и практика скриптовых языков живут в разных реальностях.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр если честно, это очень похоже на прямое нарушение SOL**ID** в не самом лучшем виде(хоть это и всего лишь рекомендации, но придуманы они не просто так). В любом случае за все время общения со скриптовыми языками я ни разу не сталкивался с подобными проблемами в которых приходилось бы плодить что-то похожее или отсутствие подобных механизмов меня как-то напрягало. Поэтому не имея под рукой никаких реальных живых примеров, мне сложно судить о полезности подобных механизмов. В сожалению общаться на подобные темы не очень удобно в рамках ruSO.

Comment: да, тут нужны более реальные примеры с более объёмным кодом. И да - это нарушает SOLID - о чём я в вопросе снизу написал. Но SOLID - это не принципы ( точнее на деле это нельзя воспринимать как то что нельзя нарушать ), это рекомендации которые направлены на решение определённых задач и противоречат друг другу, см. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556137/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-ocp-%D0%B8-dip-%D0%B8%D0%B7-solid-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-yagni . Спасибо за мнение, удачи!

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр принципы и методологии в основном рекомендации, которые можно соблюдать или не соблюдать. Программист сам решает, когда это стоит делать, а когда не стоит. Главное разобраться, какие проблемы методы решают и с чем можно столкнуться при их несоблюдении(потенциальные узкие места), а дальше уже самому решать исходя из опыта. Ладно, удачи и Вам.

Comment: дополнил вопрос примером обоснованности

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понимаю, в указании этого только на уровне документации беда в том, что написанное там непроверяемо или проверяемо очень тяжело: требует дополнительного разбора, статического анализа или ещё каких-то дополнительных этапов.

---

Я иногда встречаю в [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure) в этой роли **протоколы**.

Протокол это абстракция, которая содержит несколько сигнатур методов, а в её документации пишутся указания и ограничения по их реализации.

*Пока что* похоже на **интерфейсы**. И объявление протокола действительно приводит к созданию одноимённого интерфейса, который можно реализовать кодом **не** на Clojure, а, скажем, на Java.

А теперь *весёлая* часть: реализовывать интерфейс может любой тип, и этот факт может быть объявлен *где угодно*. В самом интересном случае вы можете реализовать поддержку **протокола** из одной библиотеки **типом** из другой библиотеки в *собственном коде*. Без вмешательства в код библиотек! Реализовывать протоколы можно даже встроенными типами!

Фактически выходит, что проверка на тип протокола автоматически проверяет объект на принадлежность тип-сумме* реализаций (правда, в рантайме: надо писать тесты). Но с возможностью добавить туда что-то ещё.

В ООП это аналогично набору классов-обёрток с общим предком или интерфейсом. Значение при этом нужно заворачивать в обёртку **до** передачи по месту использования, вручную, поскольку на том этапе ещё неизвестно, какую обёртку выбрать. Clojure делает это сам, следуя типу значения. Просто синтаксический сахар, никакого волшебства. Но, в конце концов, мы о языковых средствах и говорим.

---

И, конечно, есть разного рода ассерты. Некоторые из них могут автоматически исключаться при компиляции в релиз. Они обычно выражают то же, что и в документации, но в проверяемом машиной виде. Может показаться минусом тот факт, что за документацией нужно лезть в исходники, но... может, тот факт, что документация и код не разделены, это даже плюс?

- Банальное предусловие (и единственное *встроенное в язык* из представленных решений):

  ```clj
  (defn lookup [arg]
    {:pre [(or (vector? arg)
               (isa? arg String)
               (isa? arg Integer))]}
    (...реализация...))
  ```
- Есть `core.typed`, дополнительная "статическая типизация" (работающая больше как тесты, не при компиляции, а только при явном запуске), там просто есть функция `U`, принимающая набор типов и возвращающая их тип-сумму*. Это кладётся в аннотацию, рядом с реализацией, хотя можно положить и отдельно. Правда, `core.typed` так и остался нишевой "игрушкой", которой надо аннотировать *вообще всё*, иначе от проверок мало толку, а вывод типов работает плохо.

  ```clj
  (t/ann lookup [(t/U t/Str
                      (t/Vec t/Any)
                      t/Int        ) -> DbResult])
  ;; А реализация где-то в другом месте
  ```
- Схемы, самый популярный вариант из них это `prismatic/schema`. Там `either`, прямой аналог `U` из `core.typed`, признан устаревшим, т. к. он был медленным и его нарушения выдавали странные сообщения об ошибках. Частично его функции теперь выполняет `cond-pre` (и наш случай тоже):

  ```clj
  (s/defn lookup [arg :- (s/cond-pre s/Str
                                     [s/Any]
                                     s/Int)]
    (...реализация...))
  ```

  Это компактный вариант. Можно результат `cond-pre` записать куда-то и делать по нему `validate`/`check` явно.

Необходимо, конечно, чтобы проверки запускались. В тестах, например. Это отдельный запуск, и можно было бы с тем же успехом разбирать комментарии и делать проверки на их основе, но это технически сложнее.

---

**тип-сумма* это операция над типами, возвращающая тип, под который подходят значения всех составляющих типов.