# Трактовка принципа Открытости-Закрытости

Tags: java, ооп, solid

Пример с дополнением интерфейса:

```
class Playback {
    private Media current;

    public void play(Media media) {
        current.stop();
        current = media;
        current.play();
    }

    public void next() {
        Media media // получение следующей по какому либо алгоритму
        play(media);
    }

    public void prev() {
        Media media // получение предыдущей по какому либо алгоритму
        play(media);
    }
}
```

Пример с добавлением классов операций:

```
class Playback {
    private Media current;

    public Media current() {
        return current;
    }

    public void play(Media media) {
        current.stop();
        current = media;
        current.play();
    }
}

abstract class PlayOperation {
    private Playback playback;    

    public void execute() {
        Media media = provide();
        playback.play(media);
    }

    protected abstract Media provide();
}

class NextOperation extends PlayOperation {
    public Media provide() {
        Media media // получение следующей по какому либо алгоритму
        return media;
    }
}

class PrevOperation extends PlayOperation {
    public Media provide() {
        Media media // получение предыдущей по какому либо алгоритму
        return media;
    }
}

class RandomOperation extends PlayOperation {
    private Random random;    

    public Media provide() {
        Media media // получение рандомной
        return media;
    }
}
```

Пример с новыми классами выглядит привлекательнее, а стоит ли оно того?

Comment: Ну, на мой взгляд, тут всё зависит от более широкого архитектурного контекста. Если нужны такие сущности, которые олицетворяют операции, в контексте архитектурного решения более высокого уровня (скажем, к GUI привязывать надо), то да, в этом может быть смысл. А если нет такого контекста, то писать шаблоны ради самих шаблонов я бы не стал - уважаю Оккама.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Пример с добавлением классов операций

То что вы описали в примере, это почти шаблон проектирования "Посетитель" . `NextOperation` , `PrevOperation` , `RandomOperation` - посетители класса `Playback` . В данном случае этот шаблон вряд ли обоснован, так как он призван добавлять поведение иерархии классов, и он действительно при работе с иерархией играет на **OCP** (т.к. необходимость добавления поведения  в дерево наследников с помощью добавления метода в базовый класс как-раз нарушит OCP). У вас же класс один `Playback` - **OCP** не будет нарушено в первом случае - `Playback` открыт для расширения наследованием (если конечно поменять `private` на `protected`), и закрыт для изменения (это значит, что переписывать его вам не требуется для доработки поведения в наследниках).

Нельзя не увидеть минус второго подхода - вы серьёзно усложняете систему, размазывая простую логику на множество классов ( это [Anti-SRP](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/10/about-design-principles.html) ). Поэтому я бы посоветовал оставить первый вариант, как минимум, когда система простая - так усложнять её нельзя, [YAGNI против](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556137/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-ocp-%D0%B8-dip-%D0%B8%D0%B7-solid-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-yagni).

Но если `Playback` становится базовым классом иерархии - использование посетителей будет уже обосновано, и следует добавить метод `visit(PlayOperation operation)`, при чём возможность посещения `Playback` - не значит что метод `next()`, например,  обязательно должен быть вынесен в класс-посетитель: в посетителей лучше выносить дополнительные операции, а основные - оставлять внутри класса.

Comment: Также надо заметить, что OCP - весьма спорный принцип, для проектов, не являющихся библиотекой/фреймворком. Для остального зависимости на изменяемую в абстрактном классе логику прослеживаются быстро с помощью IDE (при неизменной догме - доступ программистов ко всем сорцам, разумеется) . Но с другой стороны, если воспринимать OCP не прямо - он гласит "делайте объекты гибкими" что обязательно нужно принимать во внимание всегда.

Comment: "переписывать не требуется" и "закрыт для изменения" - это все-таки разные вещи.

Comment: @Etki а что по вашему OCP? Добавьте ответ - тот кто будет искать информацию про OCP наткнётся и ему будет интересно :) Если трактовать закрытость - как нечто связанное с наследованием, то это уже LSP, думаю. Закрытость в OCP - это, мне кажется, гибкость компонента - которая позволяет не изменяя его код, использовать его повторно в самых разных вариациях.